# Input using std::cin doesn't work for floating point only when the value is trailed by the letter 'e' (both upper and lower case)

Tags: c++, templates

I wrote a method to get user input from std::cin and return it and it's worked for all of my tests so far except for a float or double followed by the letter 'e'.

This is the method:

```
template <typename Arg>
Arg getInput(string message = "")
{
    if (!is_fundamental<Arg>::value && typeid(string) != typeid(Arg))
    {
        return Arg();
    }

    if (!message.empty())
    {
        print(message);
    }

    Arg out;
    cin >> out;

    while (cin.fail())
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore();
        cin >> out;
    }

    cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');

    return out;

}
```

This is the method call:

```
getInput<double>("Please Enter a Double: ");
```

The method returns the correct value for everything I've tried so far but std::cin fails when the value is trailed by an 'e'.

For example: 12.34 is read as 12.34, ae1.23f1 is read as 1.23, but std::cin fails on 1.2ef and 12E because the numbers are immediately followed by and 'e'

As a note, when the return type of the method is changed to float, it still produces the same problem that double does. This doesn't make any sense to me because it's the only thing that I've found to cause the program to not work so my guess is that it's the way std::cin is handling the input.

Disclaimer: I am new to c++ from java so my code probably has some other minor errors like return Arg(); won't work if the class doesn't have a default constructor so I have to fix that.

Comment: `e` and `E` are used for scientific notation. e.g. 1e2 is 100. When a number doesn't follow the `e`, it's invalid.

Comment: Well, the characters `e` and `E` can be used to express floating point numbers using scientific notation. So it makes sense that `cin` would consider those characters as part of the `double` value it's trying to extract.

Comment: I assume that first `if` is used to protect against calling `println` with types that it does not support. But, try using `getInput` with one of those types and you will find that the `if` doesn't help. Those `println` will still *try* to compile and fail.

Comment: FYI: `while (cin.fail())` if we ever enter this loop, there's a chance we'll never get out of it.

Comment: For a **minimal** compilable example, most of the code in the question is irrelevant and should have been removed.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux the print statement will run without that but the only reason I put that was so that it wouldn't have to run and call cout if there was nothing to pass through. I don't know a lot about how cout works but I figured it would improve performance slightly.

Comment: @PeteBecker most of the code doesn't effect the problem itself, however, I included it because I didn't know where it was going wrong at the time.

Comment: @JoshuaPaige -- remove code until the problem goes away. Put back the last thing you removed. Repeat until done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enter a number followed by an `e` (or `E`) then `cin` expects a number to be entered in *scientific notation*. If there's no integral number (negative or otherwise) after `e`, then that's not valid scientific notation and `cin` will fail to read that as a floating point `float` or `double`.

The error is similar to your inputting something like `3..`.